# Instances Conflicting - JSON objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not doing something right.

Trying to create 2 instances of data models off my json model template file and use them but I'm obviously not getting 2 different instances of the model.

**myModel.json**

```
{
    "id": null
}
```

**myNodeModule.js**

```
var myModel = require('../../entities/myModel');

module.exports = {

    find: function *(id){
        var myModelInstance1 = myModel;
        myModelInstance1.id = 1;

        var myModelInstance12 = myModel;
        myModelInstance12.id = 2;

        found.push(myModelInstance11);
        found.push(myModelInstance12);

        console.log("id: " + found[0].id);
}
```

**Problem**: it logs "2" because for some reason it applies the last initialization for myModel1.

So how do you create 2 separate object instances of myModel.json?

Comment: When I just tried your code it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function instead, which returns the object and call it.

```
function myModelFact(){
  return {
      "id": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that requiring a JSON document creates an object instance, but returns a reference to that instance (objects are passed/assigned by reference). That means that when you assign `myModel`, which is a reference to the object to another variable, you are essentially assigning a pointer to that same object. Consequently, if you modify the reference, the single instance changes and that change reflects on all references to that instance.

Try something like this instead:

```
function _getModelInstance() {
    return require('../../entities/myModel');
}

module.exports = {

    find: function(id){
        var myModelInstance1 = _getModelInstance();
        myModelInstance1.id = 1;

        var myModelInstance12 = _getModelInstance();
        myModelInstance12.id = 2;

        found.push(myModelInstance11);
        found.push(myModelInstance12);

        console.log("id: " + found[0].id);
}
```

This code will create a new instance of the object from the JSON document on demand.